# db4o: how can we get the data for only one object?

Tags: db4o

How can DB4o users get back the data for only one object?

(This is akin to getting the data for only one row of a traditional relational database table.)

With DB4o, I only know how to get the data back for a class of objects but not simply one unique object instance.

Comment: In java you can choose to use SODA, QBE or NQ (Native Queries). http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/basics/querying.htm

http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-7.12/java/api/com/db4o/ObjectContainer.html#query(com.db4o.query.Predicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just query objects and get first item out of the result (the same like in relational database)

to get it by Guid ID:

```
using (IObjectContainer session = this.GetNewSession())
{
    Dummy result = (from Dummy item in session
                    where item.Id == Guid.Parse("....")
                    select item).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

the result will be either null if item doesn't exist or the object found

other option is to get it directly by internal ID such as (or even UUID):

```
long id = ....;
using (IObjectContainer session = this.GetNewSession())
{
    Dummy result = (Dummy)session.Ext().GetByID(id);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks for your response, I believe I have answered my question, but maybe you have further input.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question (I believe):

Solution #1:

```
public List<Object> getListOfObjects(final Object o){

    List<Object> result = db.query(new Predicate<Object>(){

      @Override
      public boolean match (Object arg0){

         if(arg0.equals(o)){
            return true;
          }
        else{
            return false;
         }
    });

    return result;
  }
```

Solution #2:

```
public ObjectSet<Class<?>> getListOfObjects(Object o){

      Query q = db.query();
      q.constrain(o);
      ObjectSet<Class<?>> set = q.execute();

  return set;
}
```

Maybe someone knows if one of these solutions is better than the other, or whatever.